# Grid formatting giving extra blank space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am creating a website with three pages, two of which are the same layout. For one of the two the display: grid; works fine but on the second page, even when i copy paste the entire first page so its same code, it is giving a space to the left of the links. Please help.

Just html and css, ive tried adjusting the values but nothing helps.

```
//CSS
.r-tificial-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1vmin;

}

.coding-img {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
}

.r-tificial-text {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
}


//HTML
<div class="r-tificial-container">


             <div class="coding-img">


            </div>
            <div class="r-tificial-text">
                <div class="seclink-div"></div>
            </div>

</div>
```

it is showing me a space between coding-img and seclink-div on one page but not on the other with the exact same code. I expect no space

Comment: can you please provide screenshot or live link ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `grid-column-start` property of `.r-tificial-text` from `3` to `2` as shown below. It may help you to fix the issue you are explaining above.

```
.r-tificial-text {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 10;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: yes and it pushes it back a little bit but on the second page there is almost no gap there just the 1vmin!

Comment: @JeanArmenier could you provide me a seperate code snippets for three pages. Otherwise it is not possible understand the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding-left: 2vw; solved all my problems, go figure.